# Python Datetime Time Difference gives -999999999 in min when dif is small

Tags: python, python-datetime

In my small script I wanted to give script task time. In small time like under 1 min, I give min as **-999999999**.

But there is no problem in others. Seconds and microseconds can be got and they are int type, though min `<class 'datetime.timedelta'>`

My related code bunch is:

```
 from datetime import datetime,timedelta

 now = datetime.now()
 # some code here
 then = datetime.now()

 delta= then-now
 print(delta.seconds) # 10
 print(delta.microseconds) # 432214     
 print(delta.min) # '-999999999 days, 0:00:00'
```

In the console I give:

```
datetime.timedelta(days=-999999999)
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: datetime.min is not minutes  , it's the minimum possible value for a datetime

Comment: I'm voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Only days, seconds and microseconds are stored internally in a timedelta objects

The `min` attribute that you are accessing does not represent minutes and is actually the most negative timedelta object, `timedelta(-999999999)`

You can get the value of minutes using the `total_seconds` method from the *timedelta* object:

```
minutes = delta.total_seconds() / 60
```

Read documentation about min attribute [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.min)

Comment: the timedelta object already has a method for `total_seconds`, this also includes fractional seconds, no need to calculate that manually

Comment: yes, thanks for clarifying @talon, I have updated the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

`timedelta.min` doesn't give you minutes, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.min) the smallest possible delta value.

> timedelta.min
>
> The most negative timedelta object, `timedelta(-999999999)`.